# how to make role menu in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make role menu in laravel , i have make in User model this funcion

```
public function isTeacher() {
    return $this->where('role', '3')->exists();
}
```

and at the app.blade making this :

```
@if(Auth::user()->isTeacher())

    <li class=" btn">
        <a class="menu"  href="/">الرئيسية</a>
    </li>
    <li class=" btn">
        <a class="menu"  href="/">تقييم الأطفال</a>
    </li>
    <li class=" btn">
        <a class="menu" href="/">تسجيل طفل جديد</a>
    </li>
    <li class=" btn">
        <a class="menu" href="/indexTable">إدخال جدول الانشطة</a>
    </li>
    <li class=" btn">
        <a class="menu" href="/">مراجعة جدول الانشطة</a>
    </li>
@endif
@if (Auth::guest()) 

    <li class=" btn">
        <a href="/register" class="log"> تسجيل ولي أمر جديد </a>
    </li>
@endif
```

But it's giving me that error :

> Call to a member function isTeacher() on a non-object

Comment: The error is explicit: Auth::user() is not returning an object, probably because youre not authenticated. Try to inspect Auth::user() with var_dump() for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blade change:

```
@if(Auth::user()->isTeacher())
```

to

```
@if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->isTeacher())
```

Your check is not correct, if user is not logged Auth::user() returns null, so before calling isTeacher() you have to check that Auth::user() is an object

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the braces "()" after your isTeacher

```
@if(Auth::user()->isTeacher){
    //
}
```

Comment: In blade , you need to make it isTeacher()